# How stable is Magento2 in 2017?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

We have lots of stores from Magento 1, ready to move in Magento 2. How was your experience with Magento v2 since it was released 2 years ago?

Comment: Magento 2 has good from all perceptive like performance and  all. you can go with magento 2.1.9 or 2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expect a lot of bugs, but in 2.2+ there should be a lot of fixes. In the last months I do noticed the fixing of bugs has been going faster but there's still a lot of room for improvement. My advice is keep Magento 1 projects at 1 for now and if you have the resources/skilled developers you can use new projects with Magento 2 at your own risk.